# Encoding of copied file in MsBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, msbuild-task

I currently have a set of files which will get copied during build using MsBuild's copy task.  The files were initially set to ANSI format.  However the copied files turned into UTF-8 format.  This caused some major problems with my build process, as I was expecting the copied files to still be in ANSI format.

I want the copied files to preserve the ANSI format.  How do I go about it?  I looked through msdn and couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the relevant msbuild tasks that are causing the encoding change to the question?  I just did a simple test using the copy task and the file retained the ansi formating in the destination location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files were modified by the Detokenise task before the copy, so all I had to do was to add the appropriate TextEncoding to the task and things worked. Thanks.